# How to stop PHP cron job after 30 minutes from sh file

Tags: php, yii, cron, sh

I'm running a php yii2 cron from cronjob through a sh file every minute, so if previous job doesn't complete within a minute so it won't execute more than 1 time. But my problem is that, it got stuck some time and i have to manually kill this process. How can i kill a cronjob if it running from past 30 minutes.
Currently my sh file is like below:

```sh
if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep cron/my-cron-action; then
        exit 0
else
        php /home/public_html/full-path-to-project/yii cron/my-cron-action
        exit 0
fi
```

Comment: A quick thought is that you could drop a PID file somewhere (such as `/var/run`) and then have your file check the creation timestamp on that and kill anything older than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a test . Use `check_test_demo.sh` to detect `test_demo.sh`

```sh
#test_demo.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $(date +%s) > ~/temp_timestamp.log
echo process start
while [ 1 ]; do
    date
    sleep 1
done
```

```sh
#check_test_demo.sh


#!/usr/bin/env bash
process_num=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep  test_demo.sh | wc -l)
if [ $process_num -gt 0 ]; then
        now_time=$(date +%s)
        start_time=$(cat ~/temp_timestamp.log)
        run_time=$((now_time - $start_time))
        if [ $run_time -gt 18 ]; then
            ps aux | grep -v grep | grep  test_demo.sh | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}' | sh
            nohup ~/dev-project/wwwroot/remain/file_temp/test_demo.sh  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
            echo "restart success"
            exit
        fi
        echo running time $run_time seconds
else
        nohup ~/dev-project/wwwroot/remain/file_temp/test_demo.sh  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        echo "start success "
fi
```

answer, I don't know if it's right. You can try.
**I think you should record the start time of a process first**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
process_num=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep cron/my-cron-action | wc -l)

if [ $process_num -gt 0 ]; then
        now_time=$(date +%s)
        start_time=$(cat ~/temp_timestamp.log)
        run_time=$((now_time - $start_time))
        if [ $run_time -gt 1800 ]; then
            ps aux | grep -v grep | grep  cron/my-cron-action | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}' | sh
            echo $(date +%s) > ~/temp_timestamp.log
            php /home/public_html/full-path-to-project/yii cron/my-cron-action
            echo "restart success"
            exit
        fi
        echo "process running time : $run_time seconds ."
else
        echo $(date +%s) > ~/temp_timestamp.log
        php /home/public_html/full-path-to-project/yii cron/my-cron-action
        echo "process start success"
fi
```